# How to link chart to database query in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, charts

I currently am making a GUI that contains buttons that when pressed run queries in a local SQL Server database, narrowing the number of entries that display on screen based on a "SignalID".

The database is already binded to the project and successfully runs the query when a button is pressed. However, I am trying to get the values returned from the query to display on a chart in the GUI.

For example, when I press the "Phase Angle" button, Visual Studio runs the query associated with that button and outputs "SignalID", "Timestamp", and "Value" for numerous entries in the database. I want all of the numbers from the "Value" column to be plotted on the chart so that the user can analyze how the values have changed over time.

Please let me know if you need any additional information to understand my question.

Thank you for your help and time!